# Can't build workspace in spring tool suite

Tags: spring

I am having a problem while creating a  spring roo project in spring tool suite..
the problem is it says `"building workspace has encountered a problem.error occured during the build.`

**on  viewing  details:**

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'first'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.4
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.4
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.4
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your downloaded dependencies got corrupted somehow.

Try running:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: can you tell me the step to install mvn in spring tool suite

Comment: how are you managing the maven dependencies? also one way would be deleting aspectj-maven-plugin folder and its content from .m2. You application will try to redownload it

Comment: Now I am getting another problem when i run the mvn command then it says that scanning for project and build failure just like this how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I do answer beacuse I do not have enough reputation to make comment.So;

In STS I got the same error then found @dhamibirendra's answer and I tried and it worked in different way. (Right Clik On Project -->Run as Maven Build(not 3dot)) then write U- clean install on goal and run.(Do not forget to set Maven Runtime to external) After is done I got same error again on same project. Then I delete existing project and create new one and works with no problem. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click On Project -->Run as Maven Build and click on the option on build clean and install one by one and also run this command in the Goal section U- clean install and click on Run.And refresh the project if you still see the problem then please delete the old project and create new one.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the pom.xml file and paste it again in web content folder.This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).